# Closed orbits and reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group defined over a field $k$ and $X$ an affine $G$-variety.

In the case $k$ is algebraically closed we have the following result:

Let $x\in X$ such that the orbit $G\cdot x$ is closed, then the stabilizer $G_x$ is reductive.

Is this result also valid for more general fields, as perfect fields?

Comment: @Ana The answer seems to be (trivially) yes, if the question is stated correctly. Please write in detail, what result you want to be valid over more general fields.

Comment: I'd also need to see a more precise formulation: are the groups in question assumed to be connected? any restriction on the characteristic of the field?  Basically you are looking at a reductive group `$G$`  and affine quotient `$G/H$` here.  The algebraically closed case in any characteristic is documented in papers by Richardson, Cline-Parshall-Scott, Borel, Haboush, and others.  What is your own starting point?

Comment: I know that the result is true for $k$ algebraically closed, what i want to know is if it remains valid for more general fields.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: Why the answer is yes? I can not see a reason for this even for algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @m07kl: Write $Y=G\cdot x$, then $Y$ is a closed subvariety of the affine variety $X$, hence $Y$ is an affine variety. Since the quotient variety $Y=G/G_x$ of the connected reductive group $G$ is affine, we conclude that $G_x$ is a reductive (not necessarily connected).  I do not remember a reference to this standard fact; ask Jim Humphreys.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: Why $G_x$ is a reductive? I don't understand. By the way, you only need local closeness, isn't?

Comment: @JimHumphreys: Do you have a reference for this fact?

Comment: See Jim's comment to [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/156963/4149). The assertion is contained in his book, but I cannot find it now....

Comment: One needs closeness, not just local closeness. Then $Y$ is affine, hence $G_x$ is reductive.

Comment: I found this note https://www.staff.uni-mainz.de/pommeren/MathMisc/ClOrb.pdf