# Quotient of an algebraic group by a closed algebraic subgroup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a complex, linear algebraic group and $H\subseteq G$ a closed **and normal** subgroup. Then, the quotient $G/H$ has the structure of a affine variety. I am looking for the most "modern" reference in English language for this statement. I would prefer a graduate level textbook most. Anything I find, however, restricts to the reductive case, which is not general enough for me.

Comment: The statement isn't true. Take $G=SL_2$ and $H = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \ast \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$. The quotient $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$, which is not affine.

Comment: I think you want to claim that $G/H$ must be quasi-projective.

Comment: @Jesko: Note that working over the complex field is unimpotant here.  In general, the quotient of a reductive group by a closed subgroup is affine if and only if the subgroup is also reductive.

Comment: And for general $G$ it's true if $H$ is normal ;)

Comment: This is proved in linear algebraic groups by Humphreys.  The basic idea is that you can find a representation of $G$ such that the stabilizer of a specific line is exactly $H$

Comment: @Daniel: I basically copied Chevalley/Borel.   The idea is elementary (once Chevalley thought of it): realize $H$ as isotropy group of a line in a representation $G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$, then pass to the projective space $P(V)$ and embed $G/H$ there.

Comment: @Jim Humphreys and Piotr Achinger: My previous reference was [this paper by Chevalley](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SCC/SCC_1956-1958__1_/SCC_1956-1958__1__A8_0/SCC_1956-1958__1__A8_0.pdf), see Proposition 8 and his comment in the very last paragraph below that. I apparently skipped over the part where he requires the subgroup to be **normal**.

Comment: Anways, since this is in Mr. Humphreys' book, my question is void (and more importantly, my confusion lifted). I will accept Peter Crooks' answer so this is no longer an open question. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove that $G/H$ is quasi-projective, and a reference is Theorem 4.4.1 of Algebraic Quotients, Torus Actions, and Cohomology by A. Bialynicki-Birula, ‎J. Carrell, ‎and W.M. McGovern.

Comment: Note that this is a standard textbook fact, which I guess goes back to the Chevalley seminar.    An early reference is Theorem 6.8 in Borel's 1969 lecture notes *Linear Algebraic Groups*, published in an expanded edition as GTM 126 by Springer-Verlag.  (Borel's algebraic geometry language is modern enough  for this purpose.)

Comment: Just to clarify, Jim Humphreys' comment is referring not to the general coset space construction as in this answer, but rather to the finer assertion of the affineness property when $H$ is normal in $G$. (His reference is to Chapter II of Borel's book.)

Comment: No, my reference to Borel's Theorem 6.8 involves the general case of a quotient $G/H$ for any closed subgroup $H$.   Of course, when $H$ is normal it's also shown that $G/H$ has the structure of an affine algebraic group.   But the quasi-projective proeprty of the quotient is general.

Comment: @JimHumphreys Is the quotient quasi-projective even if the algebraic group is not necessarily affine?

Answer (score 3):

Given an affine (not necessarily algebraic) group $G$ over an arbitrary field and
its closed normal subgroup $H$, the fpqc quotient sheaf $G/H$ is affine. A simple proof of this fact, which uses the language of Hopf algebras, was given by M. Takeuchi, A correspondence between Hopf ideals and sub-Hopf algebras. Manuscripta Math. 7 (1972), 251–270. The proof of the theorem in Section 16.3, of Waterhouse,
Introduction to affine group schemes, Springer GTM 66, seems based on Takeuchi's idea.